# Make columns out of a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables.

The first table is a directory of my vehicles, and the second one is a table where I have the date and odometer reading of that vehicle (there might be more than 1 trip per day per vehicle). I want to have an output where I can have some analysis of whether a vehicle has odometer readings. Some of them could be reported as 0, which is what I want to be able to see or even maybe have no data at all.

**TBLVehicles**:

```
Vehicle       Group
-----------------
100             A
101             A
102             B
103             B
104             C
105             C
```

**TBLTrips**:

```
Vehicle    StartDate    Odometer
-----------------------------------------
100        2018-01-12    100
101        2018-05-12    1000
101        2018-05-12    1010
103        2018-05-12    500
103        2018-06-12    505
105        2018-06-12    0
105        2018-06-12    0
```

I would like getting an output like the one below where I can see which vehicle has a valid odometer per day in a specified date range. It would even be nice to have a total column at the end to see which ones have absolutely no odometer in that date range.

**OUTPUT**

```
Vehicle     Group   2018-01-12  2018-02-12  2018-03-12  2018-04-12  2018-05-12  2018-06-12
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100          A         1          0          0            0           0         0
101          A         0          0          0            0           2         0
102          B         0          0          0            0           0         0
103          B         0          0          0            0           1         1
104          C         0          0          0            0           0         0
105          C         0          0          0            0           0         2
```

Comment: Hi, i think you have to use pivot with dynamic query.

Comment: Are the columns DAYS or Months.  If days we're talking about 152 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one would require DYNAMIC SQL.

The columns are MONTHS, but it is a small matter to switch to days.

**Example**

```
-- Generate Date Full Date Range
Declare @D1 date,@D2 date
Select @D1=Min(StartDate),@D2=Max(StartDate) from TBLTrips

Select Top (DateDiff(Month,@D1,@D2)+1) D=DateAdd(Month,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@D1) 
 Into  #Dates
 From  master..spt_values n1


-- Generate Columns
Declare @Cols varchar(max) = stuff( (Select ','+QuoteName(D) From #Dates Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  

-- Generate Dynamic SQL
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select Vehicle,StartDate,Odometer=sign(Odometer) From TBLTrips
        Union 
        Select A.Vehicle 
              ,B.D
              ,0
         From  TBLVehicles A
         Cross Join #Dates B
      ) Src
 Pivot (sum([Odometer]) For [StartDate] in (' + @Cols  + ') ) p
 Cross Apply ( Select Total = '+replace(@Cols,',','+')+' ) T 
'
--Print @SQL 
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **EDIT - Requested UPDATE**

```
Declare @D1 date,@D2 date
Select @D1=Min(convert(Date,TripStart)),@D2=Max(convert(Date,TripStart)) from EMS_trip_Data2

Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@D1,@D2)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@D1) 
 Into  #Dates
 From  master..spt_values n1


-- Generate Columns
Declare @Cols varchar(max) = stuff( (Select ','+QuoteName(D) From #Dates Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  


-- Generate Dynamic SQL
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select Vehicle,TripStart=convert(Date,TripStart),StartOdometer=sign(StartOdometer) From EMS_trip_Data2
        Union 
        Select A.Vehicle 
              ,B.D
              ,0
         From  VehicleSummary2 A
         Cross Join #Dates B
      ) Src
 Pivot (sum([StartOdometer]) For [TripStart] in (' + @Cols  + ') ) p
 Cross Apply ( Select Total = '+replace(@Cols,',','+')+' ) T 
'
--Print @SQL 
Exec(@SQL)
```

> **EDIT-2 With New Column**

```
Declare @D1 date,@D2 date
Select @D1=Min(convert(Date,TripStart)),@D2=Max(convert(Date,TripStart)) from EMS_trip_Data2

Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@D1,@D2)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@D1) 
 Into  #Dates
 From  master..spt_values n1


-- Generate Columns
Declare @Cols varchar(max) = stuff( (Select ','+QuoteName(D) From #Dates Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  


-- Generate Dynamic SQL
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (
        Select Src1.*,VS.[Group]
         From  (
                Select Vehicle,TripStart=convert(Date,TripStart),StartOdometer=sign(StartOdometer) From EMS_trip_Data2
                Union 
                Select A.Vehicle 
                      ,B.D
                      ,0
                 From  VehicleSummary2 A
                 Cross Join #Dates B
                ) src1
         Join VehicleSummary2 VS on src1.Vehicle = VS.Vehicle
      ) Src
 Pivot (sum([StartOdometer]) For [TripStart] in (' + @Cols  + ') ) p
 Cross Apply ( Select Total = '+replace(@Cols,',','+')+' ) T 
'
--Print @SQL 
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @John , this kind of output is exactly what i am looking for, for some reason my tables comes out all with 0's. im trying to make the example with my DB in SQLfiddle but it won't let me build my schema. Could it be cause my Vehicle columns are varchar?

Comment: @pato.llaguno Should not matter.  Are the columns MONTHS or DAYS ?   If Months, are all odometer reads on the 12th?

Comment: i have tried both ways, https://pastebin.com/ZZAAkzU2 that is a small portion of the db, the dates are from december 1st 2018 until 14 of Jan 2019

Comment: @pato.llaguno Give me a moment

Comment: @pato.llaguno OK, I see the problem.  You have datetime not date.   Again, do you want the columns by DAY or MONTH ?

Comment: @pato.llaguno See EDIT - Requested Update

Comment: @pato.llaguno Just a quick note.  vehicle 10000 is NOT listed in VehicleSummary2 that is why you will see NULLs on the first row

Comment: Thank you very much, it did what i was asking i will try and learn how to use pivot out of this example.

Comment: @pato.llaguno Take a little time dissecting the query.  If you get stuck, I can add a little narrative.

Comment: that would be awsome!

Comment: it appears i couldn't figure out by myself how this query works completly since i am trying to agregate another column before all of the dates and after the vehicle number but i get an error. the column is inside the vehiclesummary table and i am trying something like this. `Select A.Vehicle,A.Group ,B.D` but i get an error, could you help me with the narrative to try and understand this? thanks!

Comment: @pato.llaguno Having a little trouble with the visual.  Perhaps you can edit your question and add the modified desired results.

Comment: @pato.llaguno See EDIT-2   We just added a JOIN to the vehicle summary to get the Group attached.

Comment: @pato.llaguno You may want the change Join VehicleSummary2 to LEFT Join VehicleSummary2 if you are missing a vehicle in the summary table

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a script regarding what you want. I have used `CTE` and `PIVOT` to find what you want. Also, I have created "Dates" temp table. If you planning to run this report multiple time I advise you to create a static table to increase the performance.
I hope this method can work for you.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TBLVehicles') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TBLVehicles;
CREATE TABLE #TBLVehicles
(
    VehicleId   INT
);

INSERT INTO #TBLVehicles
VALUES (100),(101),(102),(103),(104),(105);

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TBLTrips') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TBLTrips;
CREATE TABLE #TBLTrips
(
     VehicleId  INT
    ,StartDate  DATE
    ,Odometer   INT
);

INSERT INTO #TBLTrips
VALUES
 (100,'2018-01-12',100  )
,(101,'2018-05-12',1000 )
,(101,'2018-05-12',1010 )
,(103,'2018-05-12',500  )
,(103,'2018-06-12',505  )
,(105,'2018-06-12',0    )
,(105,'2018-06-12',0    );

DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DateArray VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @StartDate DATE='2018-01-12'
DECLARE @EndDate DATE='2018-06-12'

IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#Dates') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Dates;
CREATE TABLE #Dates
(
    Date    DATE
);

WHILE @StartDate<=@EndDate
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Dates
SELECT @StartDate
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@StartDate)
END

SELECT @DateArray=ISNULL(@DateArray+',','')+'['+CAST(Date AS VARCHAR)+']' FROM #Dates ;


SET @SQLString=
'
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT V.VehicleId
    ,T1.Date
    ,CASE WHEN T2.Odometer IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END OdometerKey
FROM #TBLVehicles V
LEFT JOIN FROM #Dates T1 ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN #TBLTrips T2 ON V.VehicleId = T2.VehicleId AND T1.Date=T2.StartDate
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
PIVOT
(SUM(OdometerKey) FOR Date IN ('+@DateArray+')
) PVT
';

 EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLString
--PRINT(@SQLString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pivot with a left join from Vehicles to Odometer so all vehicles are represented in the output

```
Create Table Vehicle    
(
Id Int
)
Insert Into Vehicle Values
(100),
(101),        
(102),
(103),
(104),
(105)

Create Table Odometer
(
Vehicle_Id Int,
StartDT Date,
Odometer Int
)
Insert Into Odometer Values
(100,'2018-01-12',100),
(101,'2018-05-12',1000),
(101,'2018-05-12',1010),
(103,'2018-05-12',500),
(103,'2018-06-12',505),
(105,'2018-06-12',0),
(105,'2018-06-12',0);



Select 
   id ,
 [2018-01-12],
 [2018-02-12],
 [2018-03-12],
 [2018-04-12],
 [2018-05-12],
 [2018-06-12],
 [2018-07-12],
 [2018-08-12],
 [2018-09-12],
 [2018-10-12],
 [2018-11-12],
 [2018-12-12],
 (
    isnull([2018-01-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-02-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-03-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-04-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-05-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-06-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-07-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-08-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-09-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-10-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-11-12],0)+
    isnull([2018-12-12],0)
 ) As Total

From 
(
Select * From Vehicle v Left Join 
Odometer o On v.Id = o.Vehicle_Id 
) p
Pivot
(
count(Odometer)
For StartDT In ([2018-01-12],[2018-02-12],[2018-03-12],[2018-04-12],[2018-05-12],[2018-06-12],[2018-07-12],[2018-08-12],[2018-09-12],[2018-10-12],[2018-11-12],[2018-12-12])
) pv
order by pv.id
```